# Converter projeto Java + WindowBuilder para Android ou Web

Tags: java, android, maven, window-builder

Boa tarde,

Teria alguma possibilidade de converter o meu projeto Java + Windowbuilder para dispositivos Android ou para Web? Vi que é possível converter Java para Maven mais outra dúvida é... O que aconteceria com os JFrames?

Obrigado!

Comment: Creio que não tenha como. Você pode reaproveitar algumas coisas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Boa tarde Júnior

Converter diretamente não é possivel, a parte de visualização e controller ao menos, terão que ser reescritos para adequar a API da plataforma na qual fará a implementação.

Java é uma linguagem de programação e Maven é um gerenciador de build para a linguagem Java, essa conversão não existe, você apenas passa a utilizar o Maven para gerenciar as dependencias da sua aplicação Java.

WindowBuilder você esta se referindo ao uso da API Swing e AWT de Java, como disse antes não é possivel rodar em Android ou Web, porém é possivel construir Applets que são aplicações Java que rodam na Web, apesar de hoje em dia é raro encontrar alguem utilizando ou construindo.

Existe uma outra API no Java para construir aplicações Desktop e que podem ser portadas para Android, o JavaFX.

```
Ref: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javase-clienttechnologies.htm
Ref2: http://gluonhq.com/open-source/javafxports/
```